# Building image masonry like Facebook photos (architecture)

Tags: javascript, css, gallery, masonry

I've gone through lots of masonry libraries before posting this question, but I could not find anything similar. So, I would greatly appreciate your advice.

What I'm trying to achieve is a perfect square masonry with just several (1-5) images - similar to Facebook images layout. E.g:

[image]

Also, I've been trying to build it myself from scratch, but there are some difficulties: As I understand, one can never know image height and width before it is partly or fully loaded. Even though, at first I need dimensions of only the first image to decide on a grid style, this waiting does not seem a good solution. On fb, the grid seems(?) to be determined from the beginning.

I have doubts that in case of FB the positions and sizes of these images are calculated in back-end and css is used only for masking, because server returns already resized images and maybe it even stores these alignment data to avoid repeated calculations.

Could you share your experience on this or redirect me to some library that solves this task? Actually, this algorithm should be easier than perfect masonry algorithms with many images, because only 1-5 images needs be shown here and all cases are determined based on whether first image is a portrait, landscape or square and whether it fills container width.

Thanks!

Comment: Those smaller images are just cut to squares, and the larger one to about double the width (little extra for the margin between two small square images.) So this doesn't need much of an algorithm - an image either fills a whole row, or it has space for a second one of the same size next to it. So at most you would need to do some ordering in this step, to avoid large - square - large situations. And once you got that, even simple floating will do the trick.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the comment. This image is just for an example. This alignment is for the case when first image is a landscape and there are total of 3. For instance, if first one was a portrait, than it would cover a vertical half. Also, if the first one had width smaller than the container, the positioning would be completely different. Masking images to squares can be done easily with css.

The main problem is how to know image size without waiting for images to load, and whether this positioning should be calculated and stored on server-side just once.

Comment: Well if you don't want to have any wait times, then yes, you could/should do the necessary calculations beforehand, server-side.